# Dynamic fielderror struts2 validation

Tags: validation, tags, struts2, ognl

i'm dynamically generating fields (from a hashmap):

```
<s:iterator value="app.fields" status="field">
  <s:set name="findex" value="%{'app.fields[' + #field.index + '].id'}"/>           
  <s:fielderror value="%{#findex}"/>
  <s:textfield name="%{#findex}" />
</s:iterator>
```

This method sets up the textfield ok:

```
<input type="text" id="saveapp_app_fields_1__id" value="[DE]Enter an ID" name="app.fields[1].id">
```

but not the fielderror. 
I add the fielderrors manually in the validate method. but all field errors get displayed n times for each fielderror tag. wich implies that what is actually happening is that the `#findex` seems to evaluate to null and i'm adding n `<fielderror/>` tags.

I could extract the field errors manulally in the jsp but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance. Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a fielderror declared in that way.  Perhaps try:

```
<s:fielderror> 
<s:param value="%{#findex}" /> 
</s:fielderror>
```